# Helm can't render YAML ConfigMap with {{ ... }} expression in it

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have an argoCD application that works fine and I don't understand why the error appears during processing config.yaml file. I just tried to re-deploy the app.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-notifications-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  context: |
    argocdUrl: https://argo.*****.com
  service.teams: |
    recipientUrls: 
      argocd: $channel-teams-url
  template.app-created: |
    email:
      subject: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has been created.
    message: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has been created.
```

{{.app.metadata.name }} caused the error "Error: template: notifications/templates/config.yaml:16:34: executing "notifications/templates/config.yaml" at <.app.metadata.name>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.metadata Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML"

Everything worked fine few days ago!
"Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has been created" should be a text in the ConfigMap...
Have no idea what to do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of your ConfigMap data includes a `{{ ... }}` Go text/template expression, and Helm tries to process it.  However, this isn't intended for Helm but rather another application that uses the same templating infrastructure, and that's why you get an error.

When you do run into this case, you need to write a Helm template expression that produces at least the `{{` marker; for example

```yaml
message: Application {{ "{{" }}.app.metadata.name}} has been created.
```

You could put more of this inside the template expression, or even break some of it out into a variable

```yaml
{{- $name := "{{.app.metadata.name}}" }}
email:
  subject: Application {{ $name }} has been created.
message: Application {{ $name }} has been created.
```

So in this last example the variable `$name` contains the string `{{.app.metadata.name}}` including the curly braces; and then the template expression `{{ $name }}` expands to that string.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works fine even with this construction
`{{ "{{" }}range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}` instead of `{{range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}` 
But the question still open - Why it woks fine before? :) 
The same version of helm and so different result...

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand ..
I found a post dated 2020 here https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2798 "Can Helm support to ignore {{expr}} which is just for configuration but not render?"
with annotation {{` ....... `}}
and everything became OK.
I'm not joking a week ago everything was fine with {{ ..... }}

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer? or additional commentary for your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).